# does extraction operator remove delimiter?

Tags: c++, input, extract

As I understand the extraction operator>> is delimitered by whitespace. Does the extraction operator remove the delimiter from the stream? E.g., say I have the file

```
6
Foo
Bar
```

and the code

```
ifstream fin(filename);
int x;
fin >> x;
```

does the filestream still contain the newline character that followed the 6 (potentially messing up subsequent getline statements)? Or was this removed in the extraction process?

Comment: Yes, and the newline was still there but it's hard to tell if it's because that is the way the extraction operator works or if there was another invisible whitespace character in the file before the newline, e.g. carriage return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the stream not consumed remains unchanged. So a subsequent call to `getline` will return an empty line.

If you are unsure about the exact file content, try `cat -A filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out. You can do

```
ifstream fin(filename);
string x;
fin >> x;
cout<<x<<"foo";
```

you will notice it ;)